# Exchange 2010 - double right brackets ( >> ) in ems every time I hit Enter

Tags: exchange-2010, syntax, powershell

Lets say I run cmdlet such as this:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$AllMBX = Get-MailboxStatistics -Database "SSYDrybulk? | Where-Object {$_.DisconnectDate -ne $NULL} | Select MailboxGuid, Database [Enter]
>> [Enter]
>>
```

[Enter] is not typed in. It s when I hit it. I cannot find out why the cmdlet is giving me the `>>`. It looks like it wants me to type in termination to indicate the end of cmdlet but I cannot find what it cold be.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing quote on the `SSYdrybulk?` term. The `>>` is there to show that it's waiting for a closing character of some kind, like a quote or a paren.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/859/

Comment: XKCD - is there anything it doesn't have a comic for?